# How to apply if/else logic in python for an excel file? (dates)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

***strong text***I got an excel file with dates, starting from 2019 till 2021. And i wanted to apply certain rules like if sales was made between 04.05.2019 and 09.05.2019 then it's a promo number 1, etc.  The output is here

[image]

**desired outcome**

[image]

Promo file
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for mask and set new values by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
mask = df['date'].between('2019-05-04', '2019-05-09')
df['new'] = np.where(mask, 'promo number 1', 'no promo')
```

---

If there is multiple values, e.g. in dictionary:

```
d = {
     '25% sales': ('2019-04-29','2019-04-30'),
     '40% sales': ('2019-05-12','2019-05-15'),
     '50% sales': ('2019-05-18','2019-05-22')
    }

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

for val, (date1, date2) in d.items():
    mask = df['date'].between(date1, date2)

    df.loc[mask, 'new'] = val

df['new'] = df['new'].fillna('no promo')
```

Comment: thank you! Should i run this code in jupyter by importing numpy library?

Comment: @Arty - Sure, added to answer.

Comment: thanks!! is there a way to put a lot of dates? Like i got over 100 promoes with different dates, just wanted to know if there is an easier way

Comment: @Arty - How looks input? Soem pairs of datetimes? Some loop?

Comment: added to the original question

Comment: @Arty - there are not years? so it means need set `28.04 - 30.04` for each year `2019, 2020, 2021` ?

Comment: there are like 3 sheets, 1st sheet 2019, 2nd sheet 2020 and 3rd sheet 2021.  Dates are different year by year. But i can add years manually, the most difficult is to put those 100 promo in jupyter

Comment: @Arty - Edited answer, can you check?

Comment: thank you very much! looks perfect, you are genius ! @jezrael